# Send JSON data from Javascript (in the Browser) to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, timezone, client-side

Currently writing an application which requires me to find out some information of the client's browser (e.g.  GetTimeZoneOffeset, Screen Width and Height, Color Depth, if JS and Java is enabled).

I need this information displayed as JSON data in a PHP file. What is the best way to do this?

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['width'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_size'] = array();
    $_SESSION['screen_size']['width'] = intval($_POST['width']);
    $_SESSION['screen_size']['height'] = intval($_POST['height']);
}


if (!isset($_SESSION['screen_size'])) {
?>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function getSize() {
                document.getElementById('inp_width').value = screen.width;
                document.getElementById('inp_height').value = screen.height;
                document.getElementById('form_size').submit();
            }
        </script>

        <!-- <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var d = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;    
            }
        </script> -->

    </head>

    <body onload='getSize()'>
        <form method='post' id='form_size'>
            <input type='hidden' name='width' id='inp_width' />
            <input type='hidden' name='height' id='inp_height' />
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>


<?php
} else {
    print_r($_SESSION['screen_size']);
}

// echo '<pre>' , var_dump($_SERVER) , '</pre>';
$lang = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$acceptHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$shopperUrl = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

echo 'Browser Languge: ';
print_r($lang);
echo '' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Accept Header: ';
print_r($acceptHeader);
echo '' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'User Agent: ';
print_r($userAgent);
echo '' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Shopper Result Url ';
print_r($shopperUrl);
echo '' . PHP_EOL;
```

I have the above code currently, but I believe I am going this the wrong way.

Comment: You need AJAX to pass values from the client to the server. That's the best I can offer with the scarce information you have shared. You might want to elaborate more on your question by adding some information about how and why this data will be used.

Comment: The 'best way' will depend on many things of which you've shared none. What have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Hi both, apologies on that - I am relatively new to Development in general. I have the code currently in the post but believe there should be a more efficient way in doing what I need it to. Some of the data I can retrieve quite easily using PHP but I believe if I gather all the data I require using Javascript and/or jQuery it will give me a cleaner code, I just can't seem to find a way in doing this.